# How to check the status of browser after every WebExecute command?

Tags: web-access, webservices, webdriver

When executing commands using `WebExecute` on the `$CurrentWebSession` like follows:

```
WebExecute[{
    "TypeElement"->{First@WebExecute["LocateElements"->"XPath"->"..."],"..."},
    "TypeElement"->{First@WebExecute["LocateElements"->"XPath"->"..."],"..."},
    "ClickElement"->First@WebExecute["LocateElements"->"XPath"->"..."],
    "OpenPage"->"..."
}];
```

I usually have to add manual pauses to make sure the page has been updated after the previous command execution and all the necessary elements have been loaded.
Is there a way to check whether all the assets of the page have been loaded yet?

Something like `$CurrentWebSession["CurrentStatus"]`?

Otherwise, the next `WebExecute` command doesn't work properly if the element it requires hasn't been loaded yet. Sometimes there is the latency from the server-side and the WL doesn't automatically wait for everything to load.